# How to update firmware of microcontroller using DALI lines of a DALI slave module?

Tags: pic, usb, serial, bootloader, dali

I have developed a DALI slave module with PIC [16F18326](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/40001839b.pdf) microcontroller. Now, I want to make a bootloader for this PIC.

The problem is, I don't have serial communication or a USB connection with the DALI slave module. The only possible way is to communicate through the DALI lines (DA+ & DA-). The DALI-USB from [Tridonic](https://www.tridonic.com/com/en/products/2622.asp) or [Lunatone](https://www.lunatone.com/en/product/dali-usb/) can be used to communicate. But, their supporting PC software allows firmware-update for their products/ devices only.

So right now, if I want to update my firmware I have to use a programming device, which is not a feasible method. Because once the DALI device is installed in a building or inside a Luminaire it is difficult to open the DALI slave module and access to the programming pins of the PIC is extremely difficult. (**`So programming using ICD or normal serial communication methods are not a solution`.**) The only available wired contacts with DALI slave module are DALI lines (DA+ & DA-) and the Power lines (L & N , through which a communication is not at all possible ).

Do anyone know how to use the DALI lines to update the PIC firmware **without having a specific PC-Software** or **how to bootload a PIC with DALI lines** ?

Comment: The answer to this boils down to "Write your own bootloader which understands DALI", and having some specific PC software is probably unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

This requirement is addressed in the [upcoming](https://www.digitalilluminationinterface.org/dali/standards.html) IEC 62386-105 standard which specifies a method of transferring firmware over DALI. However, it is some months away from being released, and would still require you to implement firmware which can write the PIC program space, and probably also to write the PC software although the main lighting companies may eventually release their own which could be used.

The standard leaves it open as to whether you partition your program space into a bootloader (which would have to have DALI capability) and one application, or two application spaces with one active at any one time, each acting as bootloader for the other.

Unfortunately this has been one of the later standards to be written in the 62386 family so companies may have implemented proprietary methods in the meantime. So unless you have the required information which is likely only available under NDA, you can't use those PC software programs with your device.